# making a CGRect off screen

Tags: ios, cgrect, cgrectmake

Is it possible to create UIImageView within a CGRect offscreen?

I will then animate it onto the screen after a user pushes a UIButton.

I know this function `CGRectMake(x,y,height, width)` but apparently x and y cannot have negative values.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Negative values of x and y are allowed and should work fine. To get better help, please explain: #1 what you did (including exact code), #2 what you expected to happen, #3 what actually happened.

Comment: Curious - what led you to believe that the x and y values can't be negative?

Comment: Oops, I didn't take into account the width of my rectangle and just never set a negetave x coordinate that was larger, thanks for you help. How do I close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. There are a couple of things that you could do. Depending on where you want it to animate in from, set the x and y of the imageview to be negative or greater than `<parentView>.bounds.size.width` or height etc. Then you can use UIView to animate changes.

So in viewDidAppear or whatever method triggers the animation you can use [From apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html):

`+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion`

to handle all of the animations. Here is an [example](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_uiview-animations/):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:<timeInSecondsOfHowLongItShouldTake>
            animations:^
            {
                    imageView.frame = <CGRectFrameOfPlaceThatYouWantItToGo>
                    //you could also make it fade in with imageView.alpha = 1;
                    //assuming you started out with an alpha < 1
            }
            completion:^(BOOL finished)
            {
                    //do something after it finishes moving 
                    //the imageview into place
            }
];
```